# Custom View TextField How To Calculate TextField Sum

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on iOS application in swift 3.0 where I am creating custom view with textfield and button calculate values for all text filed and display the sum of all textfield on the top totalText.

Code for `MainViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalText: UITextField!
var totalview:[UIView]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    yvalue = 1
    tag = 1
    count = 1
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    yvalue = 55 + yvalue
    //for i in 0...count {
        extraview = View(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 75+yvalue, width: 350, height: 50))
        extraview.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        extraview.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        extraview.tag = tag
        print("ExtraView tag=",extraview.tag)
        extraview.ActionButtonsub.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        extraview.textFiled.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeTexts(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        extraview.textFiled.tag = tag
        print("text tag=",extraview.textFiled.tag)
        self.view.addSubview(extraview)
        count = count + 1
        tag = tag + 1
    //}
}

func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    extraview.removeFromSuperview()
}

func didChangeTexts(textField: UITextField) {
        totalText.text = extraview.textFiled.text
}
```

Code for `UIView`:

```
class View: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var subView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFiled: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ActionButtonsub: UIButton!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View",owner: self, options:nil)
        self.addSubview(self.subView)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View", owner: self, options: nil)
        subView.frame = bounds
        self.addSubview(self.subView)
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cs0R.png)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to get value from more textfield and show the total textfield value to show top totaltextfiled

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, may need a little modification.

You just need to iterate through the subviews, get the textfield for each view, convert to double value and add them up along the way.

```
func calculateTotal() -> Double {
   var total: Double = 0.0
   for subview in self.view.subviews {
      if let v = subview as? View, !v.textFiled.isEmpty {
          total += Double(v.textFiled.text)
      }
   }

   return total
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone edited this and added a break.. we want to iterate through all textfields, not just the first one. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: but questioner created the only one text field

Comment: and its based on a variable, there is a counter / loop commented out. user said "button calculate values for all text filed and display the sum" ALL values. everything suggests >= 1

Answer (score 0):

If you think @Scriptable way is complex then go like below..

Simple way, you can add those textfields into one collection while creating & looping it when you need to do something.

Comment: My solution is about the same amount of work to be honest. either way is good. I done it that way so that the user didn't need to rewrite what they have already

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is applying `filter`, `flatMap` and `reduce` functions

```
let sum = (view.subviews.filter{$0 is View} as! [View]) // filters all `View` instances
    .flatMap{$0.textFiled.text} // maps all text properties != nil
    .flatMap{Double($0)} // maps all values which are convertible to Double
    .reduce(0.0, {$0 + $1}) // calculates the sum
```